# Symfony - Assets cache auto versioning

Tags: caching, symfony, assetic

I'd like to force client's cache refresh for modified assets.

Is there already a native way to do it with `asset()` like

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js')|autoversion }}"></script>
```

?

If not, I found this [really elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118886/305189) (based on file timestamp & url rewrite) to manage it.
Did someone already faced this question and would know how to extend `asset()` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [assets_version](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version) parameter, so every asset get a version string without doing extra things in the template

Comment: This is more like a solution, Thanks. I didn't know this option. The only things is it'll force the refresh for all assets...

Comment: You're right, but the performance impact on the client is not so much, as the performance impact on the server side if you have to determine the file timestamp of every file on every request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it, i'm not sure of the result but it can work.

php app/console assetic:dump --watch

Comment: This is for dumping assets on the server. The client still won't be aware of any change.